# @font-face does not work @IE8 and lower

Tags: internet-explorer-8, font-face, webfonts

i have a problem and have no idea how to solve it.
The @font-face rule works perfect in most browsers, excecpt of IE8 and lower.

I have some test file here:
http://poorscousertommy8.lima-city.de/

If i test the site in IETester (IE8) then the stil regular and bold (first and second section) works, but italic and bolditalic looks very different from other browsers.

Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't list the eot file twice for the iefix. Try it like this-

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Minion';
    src: url('Webfonts/minion-regular.eot');
    src: url('Webfonts/minion-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('Webfonts/minion-regular.woff') format('woff'),
         url('Webfonts/minion-regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('Webfonts/minion-regular.svg#minion-regular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```